# Injective and / or surjective: factorial

Tags: analysis, functions, solution-verification, factorial, inverse-function

I would like to know if my reasonment are correct, so thank you in adavance for every critic or missing detail you will point out.

The question is: consider $f: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ definied by $f(n) = n!$, hence the factorial.
I was thinking about this in some terms: function, injection, surjection.

So first of all, I would indeed say $f(n) = n!$ is a function.

Due to lack of self confidence, I searched over here for the correct definition and I found this one in an answer: "The definition of a function is: $f: A\to B$ is a function if every $x\in A$ is in relationship with at least one $y \in B$"

I didn't really get why "at least one", since for a function I would say just exacly one...

Anyway: due to this, I hence conclude $f(n) = n!$ is indeed a function.

Now, about the injectivity I say: no.

Indeed it's not true that $\forall n_1, n_2 \in\mathbb{N}$ we have $n_1! = n_2! \iff n_1 = n_2$: just take $n_1 = 0$ and $n_2 = 1$.

About the surjectivity: no again.

Indeed the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{N}$ which is ways larger than its image (or range).

But I thought: can I say it becomes surjective if the codomain becomes its range like?

$$C = \{ 1; 2; 6; 24; 120; \ldots \}$$

Also I was thinking: If we cut off $\{ 0 \}$ from the domain, then $f(n) = n!$ becomes injective too.
But this means it's bijective, hence invertible.

So then what is the inverse of $f(n) = n! \qquad $??

Comment: If you include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$ your argument for non-injectivity is correct.

Comment: Note:  many people do not consider $0$ to be a natural number.  It's fine if you do, but you should clarify that point.  Makes a difference here, since $f(0)=f(1)$ is the only failure of injectivity in the non-negative integers.

Comment: @lulu You're right! I have been taught $\mathbb{N}$ with Peano Axioms, where $0$ is in $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: And yes, every function becomes surjective if you restrict its codomain down to its image.  That's trivially true.

Comment: @Randall Thank you so much! Can you please clarify the "at least one" part in the definition of function I rewrote here? It made me to think...

Comment: In that case the inverse function $g$ is just the function $g(n)= m$ where $m$ is the unique element with $m!=n$.

Comment: @Numb3rs my only guesses are that (a) the source has the wrong definition of function or (b) that isn't the end of the definition:  there's more that follows.  Not having the source, I don't know.

Comment: @Randall Unfortunately I lost the page, ugh. But in the case there is something else, would you be able to "guess" (or know) what could be said to make that definition well posed?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's define $\mathbb{N}=\{0, 1, 2, ...\}$ to be unambiguous. Then we will denote $\mathbb{N}^+$ to be $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$.

You have a correct argument for the non-injectivity of $f$ with domain $\mathbb{N}$. $f$ is injective on $\mathbb{N}^+$, since for all $j>k\geq 1$, $j!>k!$ (why?). $f$ is not surjective on $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{N}^+$ (for example, there does not exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ or $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ such that $n!=3$). If you restrict the codomain to the image, then it is trivially surjective, and its inverse is directly related to its preimage. That is, define $f:\mathbb{N}^+\to C$ by $f(n)=n!$. Then $g:C\to\mathbb{N}^+$ is the two-sided inverse of $f$, with $g(m) = n$ where $n$ is the only element in $f^{-1}(m)$ (the preimage of $m$).